# Main layout needs invalidate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a custom LinearLayout where the next thing happens after I click on the EditText shown and after keyboard is detached:

[image: Layout transition from EditText click to soft keyboard detach by pressing back showing corrupted]

As you can see, after soft keyboard is detached from screen (pressing back for instance), view doesnt get redrawn/invalidated.

If I do use mainLayout.invalidate() it does fix the issue, the problem is, I need to call it when soft keyboard gets detached... 
I coudln't find any info/callback I could use to make the view notice of this and call invalidate() programatically.
Any help on how to fix this?